# Who can explain the meaning of this scala code

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am reading this code for a long time. I typed it into REPL and it works as well.

but I don't have any idea of what's going on here. Why and how does this even work!!!

```
import shapeless._

case class Size[L <: HList](get : Int)
object Size {
    implicit val hnilSize = Size[HNil](0)
    implicit def hconsSize[H, T <: HList](implicit tailSize: Size[T]) = 
        Size[H :: T](1 + tailSize.get)
    def apply[L <: HList](l : L)(implicit size: Size[L]) : Int = size.get
}

Size(1 :: "Foo" :: true :: HNil)
```

Can someone explain this step by step and help me understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, that's pretty thick stuff.

The mind-bender here is that `hconsSize` is recursive without actually being self referential.

Both `apply` and `hconsSize` pull in an implicit of type `Size[X]`.  There are only two implicits that could fit that bill:

1. `hnilSize`, but only if `X` is type `HNil`
2. `hconsSize` itself

So `apply` pulls in the `hconsSize` implicit, which adds 1 to the stack and pulls in another `hconsSize` implicit (not necessarily in that order).  This continues until we encounter an element of type `HNil`.  Then the `hnilSize` implicit is pulled in, the `get` is zero, the stack is unrolled and all those 1's are added up.

Result: number of elements in the shapeless HList.